# How to prevent HtmlGenericControl from html-encoding content?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, html-encode, htmlgenericcontrol

I'm writing an asp.net site (actually, a DotNetNuke module), using C#. From code-behind, I'm trying to create a `<script>` tag where I set a required js variable, then append it to the HMTL `<head>`. The js var is a (literal) array of relative urls for image files. Since the array contains strings, each item must be enclosed in quotes.

The problem is, the string between `<script>` and `</script>` is being automatically HtmlEncoded somewhere, so the quotes around each array item are being replaced with `&quot;`. That seems to take place when the `HtmlGenericControl` is rendered. Could DotNetNuke be the culprit? Could someone suggest a workaround?

My current code (running from `Page_Load` handler in my control):

```
HtmlGenericControl PreviewDataScriptTag = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
PreviewDataScriptTag.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
StringBuilder PreviewDataScriptCode = new StringBuilder();
PreviewDataScriptCode.Append("var preview_imgs = [");
string pathPrefix = @"""";
string pathSuffix = @""",";
foreach (string path in this.DocPreviewImages)
{
    PreviewDataScriptCode.Append(pathPrefix + PreviewUrlBase + Path.GetFileName(path) + pathSuffix);
}
// Remove last comma from js code
PreviewDataScriptCode.Remove(PreviewDataScriptCode.Length-1, 1);
PreviewDataScriptCode.Append("];");
PreviewDataScriptTag.InnerText = PreviewDataScriptCode.ToString();
Page.Header.Controls.Add(PreviewDataScriptTag);
```

Comment: I recommend using lower-cased names for your variables.  This is confusing to read.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm not really used to .net, and started using upper-case for everything after realizing .net developers tend to upper-case *object property names*. I guess it's a case of over correction!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Look at using the [InnerHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innerhtml.aspx) property of the node, not the InnerText property.

> The InnerHtml property does not automatically encode special characters to and from HTML entities. HTML entities allow you to display special characters, such as the < character, that a browser would ordinarily interpret as having special meaning. The < character would be interpreted as the start of a tag and is not displayed on the page. To display the < character, you would need to use the entity <.